# Is it allowed in Javascript to declare two array of same name?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

H,

Is it allowed in Javascript to declare two array of same name?
For example, in my following code i have Permissions array declared two times. One at root and one in student object. I am getting an error which im not sure is because of it

> Error: $rootScope:inprog Action Already In Progress

```
$scope.Permissions = [];
$scope.student = {
    Student: {
        FirstName: '',
        Email: ''
    },
    Permissions: []
};
```

Comment: W.r.t. your code - yes

Comment: In your case `YES` as the second is inside an `object`

Comment: You are getting error for different reason. The posted code is fine.

Comment: Usually this means that you defined $rootScope.$apply somewhere manually inside of the another angular code which has lifecycle already.